# Is there a way to list—and kill—running processes on Mac OS X in a Windows “Ctrl+Alt+Delete”-like way?

Tags: mac

So, what do you do on a Mac when a **process** (as opposed to an application) is hogging CPU, swamping your machine, and you need to kill it?

I know you can use `top` or open “Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor” and kill it from there.

But what happens when the process is already using so much CPU that doing either of those tasks is impossible?

On Windows, you can just do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> and the process list will reliably open. So no matter how much your computer is thrashing, you always have access to the list of processes.

On Mac OS, there’s <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>escape</kbd>, which reliably shows running **applications**. Fine when it’s an application causing the problem. But: what do you do if it’s a process?

Comment: Sure. Cmd/Alt/Escape only shows applications: I want it to show all processes.

Comment: @Bobby - it sounds like you've never worked on a Mac and had to use *Force Quit*. I'm pretty sure AP257 got it right.

Comment: @noloader: Well, I've got no idea what I tried to say with that comment...

Comment: @AP257 - another useful one Macs are missing is a way to quickly lock the Mac. Like Windows' *Ctrl/Alt/Delete → Lock Workstation*.

Comment: "kill -9 p-id" worked like a champ for me. Thanks guys

Comment: Is `ctrl+alt+del` in Windows related to TaskManager?

Comment: How can I kill a process in the `activity monitor`? Right Mouse click on the process does not offer a context menu and on the menu bar there is no 'kill process' for the selected one. The `cmd alt esc` shortcut and then "force quit" on a selected process works well.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Based on your desire to kill an individual process, I'm assuming that you are ok with a solution at the Terminal.  The Terminal is pretty light so should be responsive even if your system is swamped, or if you're logging in via ssh.

Beyond the basic `kill` command, which kills processes via their `pid` (which you'd need to get from either a `ps` command, or the Activity monitor), a neat trick at the terminal is the `killall` command, which allows you to kill a process **by name** rather than pid.

For example, if you know the name of your process is `my-prog-0` or whatever, you can go to the terminal and do:

```
% killall my-prog-0
```

There are a number of good options (see `man killall` for more info):

```
-s : Shows the kill commands that will be generated so you can be safe.
-u : Limits to a specified user
```

One thing to note about OS X is that some system processes will be automatically restarted if they are killed by the `launchd` daemon (I think??).  For example, if the Dock is not responsive you can do a `killall Dock` and it will restart automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and suggestions, even though it doesn't really solve the problem. Terminal can take a few minutes to start up if the machine is trashing.... and by the time it's started up, the mystery background process has usually gone away... Thanks anyway.

Comment: If that's the case then I'm not sure there's much to be done, other than figuring out what causes this thrashing process to occur and then avoiding these conditions.

Comment: Why is the `0` necessary?

Comment: A '0' is not necessary. It was included in the answer because it is typical that processes have numbers in their name.  The important thing is to match the name of the process you want to kill.

Comment: @dtlussier Typical that processes have numbers in their name? I've never seen that, well, ever. What applications are you speaking of?

Answer (score 33):

Force Quit is the alternative to Task Manager on Mac. It's fast, efficient, and kills applications really fast.

You can access this feature through two ways.

1.  Apple Icon (on the top left corner of the screen)--> Force Quit...
2. Hold <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> + <kbd> Apple/Command</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd>. This can be useful if you memorised the keyboard command and in the rare case that Finder misbehaves and freezes along it too.

Comment: Yes, it kills *applications*. That's my point! There's a background process on my machine that sometimes causes the machine to slow down massively. Force Quit doesn't show it.

Comment: Activity Monitor can be used to show all processes and kill them through there. You can quit them or force quit them within the application.

Answer (score 17):

Try the following command in terminal to list and search for process using a regex:

```
ps gx | grep 'Symantec'
```

The above example is to list all the Symantec related processes. Replace `'Symantec'` with your own phrase. Next use variations of `kill` command. You can either use:

```
kill pid
```

Replace `pid` with actual process id (the first number of a line in the output from above). Or use,

```
killall
```

as suggested before. To reiterate another useful suggestion, use

```
man kill
```

to see the manual for the `kill` command and also scroll down and see related commands which is mentioned under the `SEE ALSO` section.

Answer (score 9):

The is no process killing keyboard shorcut, only for running applications. The only way to kill processes is through Activity Monitor or through Terminal using UNIX commands.

Answer (score 5):

Go to activity monitor, find the dock and highlight it. Hit the kill button (Stopsign with X in it, top left).

Force Quit is used for simple applications, while the activity monitor can be used to kill processes.

Answer (score 3):

Use Activity Monitor to find the Process you want to kill
Look at the PID
Using Terminal type Kill PID number and then return.

This assumes you have admin or sudu access

Comment: Why not select the process and [hit the "Force a process to quit" button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E0lJu.png) on the top left corner?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to select and kill the process using the Activity monitor GUI:

[image]